# How to configure spring boot application to use aspectj transactions?

Tags: hibernate, transactions, spring-boot, aspectj

I would like to use transactions done by aspects in spring-boot aplication, but so far I mostly found help for more "ordinary" setups...

What I've managed to set up so far?

I've got those annotations on main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving=AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
```

And this in my properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

I'm starting application with java agents spring-instrument and aspectj-weaver and I can see aspects in stacktrace where I've used `@Transactional` so at least this is working.

Also, what is really strange, problem started only after I added second entity - first one worked without problem, but now I'm having this error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

From what I've noticed beanFactory is `null` when `invokeWithinTransaction` is being run on `TransactionAspectSupport` - but it's being set during bean creation  (and from what I've seen in debug when `beanFactory` is `null` `TransactionAspectSupport` won't start a transaction because it isn't able to get `TransactionManager`). I guess non-bean instance of `TransactionAspectSupport` is being created at some point and that may be the reason for my problem (but then how and why?)?

Update:

From what I've noticed `@Transactional` is handled by `AnnotationTransactionAspect` in one case, but by `JtaAnnotationTransactionAspect` in another.

Any ideas what I'm missing? Perhaps some magical property I should set?

Oh, and here are my dependencies, if that is important:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You don't need to set the current session context, as that is already done by spring. Also are you using plain hibernate or JPA? Can you also post how you are starting the application.

Comment: Well... I'm starting it by simply running main class which has ` SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);` in main method and annotations mentioned in question. Nothing fancy, since I try to keep my modifications to required minimum. EDIT: also, I run it with two -javaagent, set as described in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. I'm an idiot, who didn't look what autoimport is doing.

I've used `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` in one place and `javax.transaction.Transactional` in another.

After changing everything to spring provided @Transactional it started to work.